# how to read and write data on serial port using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, serial-port

I am creating a serial port application in which i am creating two threads one is WRITER THREAD which will write data to serial port and a READER THREAD which will read data from serial port.I know how to open, configure,read and write data on serial port but how to do it using threads.

I am using LINUX(ubuntu) and trying to open ttyS0 port programming in C.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this in the past is to set up the port for asynchronous I/O using a VMIN of 0 and a VTIME of, say, 5 deciseconds. The purpose of this was to allow the thread to notice when it was time for the application to shut down, as it could try to read, time out, check for a quit flag, and then try to read some more.

Here is an example read function:

```
size_t myread(char *buf, size_t len) {
    size_t total = 0;
    while (len > 0) {
        ssize_t bytes = read(fd, buf, len);
        if (bytes == -1) {
            if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EINTR) {
                // A real error, not something that trying again will fix
                if (total > 0) {
                    return total;
                }
                else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (bytes == 0) {
            // EOF
            return total;
        }
        else {
            total += bytes;
            buf += bytes;
            len -= bytes;
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

The write function would look as you would expect.

In your setup function, make sure to set:

```
struct termios tios;
...
tios.c_cflag &= ~ICANON;
tios.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
tios.c_cc[VTIME] = 5; // You may want to tweak this; 5 = 1/2 second, 10 = 1 second, ...
...
```

Comment: What made you believe that serial ports cannot send and receive at the same time?

Comment: i don't want to send and receive data at same time. i will first write data and after that i will read the written data using reader thread.Actually i want to implement it using threads only otherwise without thread i have already done it,please tell something how i can implement it using threads.

Comment: @Lundin Serial port connections contain ready-to-send and ready-to-receive pins specifically to control which side has the ability to send data at a given moment, as both sides cannot at the same time. I believe that is what parallel ports are for.

Comment: As I understand it, RS-232 is (or at least can be) full duplex

Comment: how those threads communicate  to serial port....be specific...don't give me any help on synchronization of threads....

Comment: Jonathan, you couldn't be more wrong here.  RS-232 can most definitely operate at full duplex, and usually does.  The Request-to-Send (RTS) and Clear-to-Send (CTS) are used for flow control when the host's buffer gets to full to accept more data.  Fact is, hardware flow control isn't used that much anymore, and certainly isn't required.  Parallel ports would line up 8 bits to be send simultaneously.  You should also know that it wasn't until the later that parallel ports would even work in a bi-directional mode.  Sure, there were status lines, but that was it.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, and I apologize for my ignorance. I misunderstood the mechanism. However, is my answer otherwise incorrect? I will edit out the bit about being half-duplex.

Comment: @Jonathan, my comments were regarding your claims on duplexing, and nothing more.

Comment: @Jonathan Take a look at Asynchronous IO. http://davmac.org/davpage/linux/async-io.html I have never done this in linux, so i'm sorry if this article doesn't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

Using of a serial port from 2 threads is simple, if only one thread reads and other thread only writes.

You should use one file descriptor for the serial port.

Open and initialize it in one thread by using normal `open`, `tcsetattr`, etc functions.
Then deliver the file descriptor to the other thread(s).

Now the reader thread can use `read()` function, and the writer can use `write()` function without any extra synchronization. You can also use `select()` in both threads.

Closing of the file descriptor needs attention, you should do it in one thread for avoiding problems.